# How to rename bazelisk to bazel

Tags: build, tensorflow2.0, bazel

I am currently trying, without great success, to build tensorflow from source.

As suggested here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source, I tried to do so by installing bazelisk. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do so as the ./compile cannot find bazel as bazelisk replaces it.

This link: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/issues/122 suggested to alias or rename the environment variable to "bazel" in the PATH.

As described in the issue above, aliasing did not work out for the configure.py.

My next step would be to rename it but I, unfortunately, was not able to figure out how the renaming of environment works under Linux.

I did add the following:`export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin`
to my .profile under my /home folder, which, the way I understand it, adds the path to Bazelisk binaries to my environment path but I am not sure how the renaming would work in this situation.

Would it be possible to explain how I could proceed?

Comment: You could try a symlink to `bazelisk` named `bazel`.

Answer (score 2):

Download the `bazelisk` binary from the [releases](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases) page and save the file as `bazel` in a directory somewhere in your `$PATH`.

For example, if you have `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` in your `.profile`/`.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`, and in `$HOME/bin`, store the `bazelisk` binary as `$HOME/bin/bazel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 more options:

1. `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bazelisk /usr/local/bin/bazel` which makes a symlink to bazelisk (personally i prefer it, because its more explicit)
2. `alias bazel='bazelisk'` in your `~/.zshrc`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`. This also works well, but there could be some issues if you want to run `vim-bazel` and such.